# iOS app runs fine on device running iOS 8 but won't display root controller correctly on iOS 7

Tags: ipad, ios7

My app runs fine on iOS 8 devices but when I switch to an iOS 7 simulator or device all I see is the navigation bar with blank space below it.  My deployment target is set to iOS 7.0.  This is an iPad only app.  I am running XCode 6.1.1.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Any idea at what point in the code this might be occurring?

Comment: I don't get any errors.  I set breakpoints in the viewDidLoad and it hits them.